# Vue 3 extends vue.js components from third party library in defineComponent

Tags: vuejs3, extends, element-ui, element-plus

I want to use third party library element-plus in my component. In `setup` `defineComponent` entends that component. In console, it would warn `Failed to resolve component: el-radio  at <App>`

In about router, Here is the about.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="popup-content"></div>
</template>

<script>
import {
  onMounted, createApp, defineComponent, nextTick,
} from 'vue';
import Test from '@/components/Test.vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    onMounted(() => {
      const myNewComponent = defineComponent({
        extends: Test,
      });
      createApp(myNewComponent).mount('#popup-content');
      nextTick(() => {
        createApp(myNewComponent).mount('#popup-content');
      });
    });
  },
}
```

Test component has used element-plus `el-raido` component, Test.vue

```
<template>
  <el-radio v-model="radio" label="1">备选项</el-radio>
  <el-radio v-model="radio" label="2">备选项</el-radio>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      radio: '1',
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I have add element-plus, and register all in main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import ElementPlus from 'element-plus';
import 'element-plus/lib/theme-chalk/index.css';
import App from './App.vue';

const app = createApp(App);


app.use(ElementPlus);
app.mount('#app');
```

[image]

I have found this question
[Extend vue.js component from third-party library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42049367/extend-vue-js-component-from-third-party-library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I **really really** don't understand what are you trying to achieve by extending your perfectly fine `Test` component BUT...

Vue 3 is very different from Vue 2 - a lot of global API's (as component registration for example) are [not global anymore](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#global-api) but are tight to a "app instance" (created by `createApp`)

So even if you register Element components in `main.js` (`app.use(ElementPlus);`), the another app instance (why!?) created in `onMounted` hook of `about.vue` component **knows nothing** about the components! That is the reason for an error...

You must register components in **every** app instance created by `createApp` you want to use them in ....

Answer (score 1):

As @Michal Levý answered, I need to register components in every app instance created by `createApp`.

Here is the working version about.vue, in case someone need.

```
<template>
  <div id="popup-content"></div>
</template>

<script>
import {
  onMounted, createApp, defineComponent, nextTick,
} from 'vue';
import Test from '@/components/Test.vue';
import ElementPlus from 'element-plus';
import 'element-plus/lib/theme-chalk/index.css';

export default {
  setup() {
    onMounted(() => {
      const myNewComponent = defineComponent({
        extends: Test,
      });
      const app1 = createApp(myNewComponent);

      nextTick(() => {
        app1.use(ElementPlus);
        app1.mount('#popup-content');
      });
    });
  },
}
```

Comment: No snark intended here—what was your goal with this example? It looks like a simplified example case. What was the real world use cases you created it to mirror?