# Vue extend component template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Is it possible to extend a component imported from an NPM package?

Right now I've tried this, but doesn't work:

```
import Foo from 'Foo'

export default {
     extends: Foo,

     template: `<p>foo</p>`
}
```

Comment: Import -> import

Comment: What do you mean with "extend a component" ? Do you just want to use the npm component inside yours ?

Comment: @KyllianVinkler, Extend = to make new instance constructor in app.

Comment: I wish to ammend the template in the package a bit. It is a typeahead package. I wish to ammend the dropdown template of this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extend another VueJS component in a single-file component? (ES6 vue-loader)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35964116/how-do-i-extend-another-vuejs-component-in-a-single-file-component-es6-vue-loa)