# Override only component template in VusJS

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have imported one node component like, "TfNavpane". Now I need to override the "TfNavpane template only as per requirement. I am using single page component which contains template, script and style tags and I can't modify the node component directly. Code snaps has given below. How can I achieve this?

**Own component:**
[image: Custom Navpane]

**Node component:**
[image: Original Navpane template]

Comment: Try extending your base component. Extends in Vue either inherit the base template, or you define a new one and overwrite it.

Comment: can you please give an example that how to overwrite it with my given code.

Comment: how about you take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35964241/6283258